# significant bits understanding

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, mips32

To find significant bit  you could up to the highest order bit.
ex.
i need help understanding significant bits (USING 32bits):

```
0000 0000 1000 1001 0111 0000 0001 1000
```

this one (the one above) has `24 significant bits`.

But my professor told me the following 0x00000000:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

has `31 significant bits` due to the sign bit, but why? Shouldn't be 32 significant bits then by default there should be 32 (8*4)bits since i am using 32 bit collection?

I'm confused because doesn't that mean 0xf0000000

```
1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

has only 31 significant bits? Shouldn't it be 32 significant bits?

Comment: He's counting all the bits including the zeros so he isnt looking at:  1000 1001 0111 0000 0001 1000 He is looking at the extended version of: 0000 0000 1000 1001 0111 0000 0001 1000

Comment: I totally miscounted, I thought there was only 24 bits, but there's 32.  Ignore me.

Comment: I've never heard of counting the number of significant bits in this fashion for integers, and can see both of those definitions as being accurate.  If the second has 31 significant bits, why do you say the first one has 24?  I think you and the professor had a misunderstanding and you need to talk to him/her.

Comment: yeah, makes sense, i'll speak to them again

Answer (score 0):

For signed integers:

- positive numbers: 0x00000000..0x7FFFFFFF (leading bit 0)
- negative numbers: 0x80000000..0xFFFFFFFF (leading bit 1)

You may interpret it as sign (1 bit) and mantissa (31 bits). It is probably what your professor meant.